# Keras Convolutional Neural Network not fitting due to data

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Can anyone tell me what I may have done wrong or is messed up? My code runs up until I fit the model. My training data consists of images of faces with labels being race. I know for sure my training data has been stored/loaded through pickle and feature normalized.
My images are all size 224 x 224.

```
    pickle_in = open("X.pickle", "rb") 
    X = pickle.load(pickle_in) # load features 
    
    pickle_in = open("y.pickle", "rb")  # load labels
    y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

    X = X/255.0 # normalize features   
   # -------------------------------------------------------------
   # convolutional neural network creation
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))    
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))    
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())  # converts 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
    model.add(Dense(64)) # fully connected layer

    model.add(Dense(1)) # output layer
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid')) # sigmoid activation function
    
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                    optimizer='adam',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=10) # train model
    # not sure why it's not working with data
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: 
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"})
```

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Most likely your labels are in a *list* type. Convert them to np.array by `y = np.asarray(y)`

Comment: Most probably, this error is because the datatype of your labels is int. Make sure to convert it to float something like -> y = np.array(y, dtype=np.float64)